# OData V3 WebApi Create and add new objects to a collection of an entity

Tags: c#, rest, odata

Considering this being my domain classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

what's the best approach/practice to create a new "Book" object, adding it to the "Author's" collection of books on the client (using the corresponding service references) and saving the new "Book" object. For instance:

```
...
Book newBook = new Book() { Title = "New Book" };
myAuthor.Books.Add(newBook);
...
```

Is it necessary to set the AuthorId of newBook? How to post this to the server? How to setup the post action in the controller? I wasn't able to find any good documentation adressing my problem.